# My C++ List[ArrayImplementation] Error

Tags: c++, c++11

when the list is empty or the some of the index is still empty it contains a default         element  0 and 1...when im going to deposit,withdraw,edit or delete it accepts an  accountnumber of 0 and 1 even if i dont created .It should output accountNumber not Found...sorry 4 my bad english ,heres my code hope u get my point..tnx

```
 #include<iostream>
 #include<cstdlib>
 #include<conio.h>
 using namespace std;

 class unsortedList{
public:
    unsortedList();
    void getLength() const;
    void insertItem(int item,string name,double balances);
    void deleteItemAt();
    void replaceItem();
    void makeEmpty();
    bool isFull()const;
    void show();
    void deposit();
    void withdraw();
private:
    int length;
    int info[10];
    string names[10];
    double balance[10];
   };
   unsortedList::unsortedList(){
length=0;
   }
   bool unsortedList::isFull() const{

return(length==10);
   }
   void unsortedList::insertItem(int item,string name,double balances){
if(isFull()){
    return;
}
names[length]=name;
info[length]=item;
balance[length]=balances;
length++;
    }
    void unsortedList::deleteItemAt(){
int location,n,found;
cout<<"Enter the Account number: ";
cin>>n;
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){

    if(info[i]==n){

    found =1;
    location =i;
    }}
    if(found==1){

    for(int i=location;i<length-1;i++)

    info[i]=info[i+1];

    length--;
    cout<<"Account Deleted";}

    else{
    cout<<"Account Number Not Found";    }
getch();
    }

    void unsortedList::show(){
for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
    cout<<"Account name: "<<names[i]<<endl;
    cout<<"Account number: "<<info[i]<<endl;
    cout<<"Account balance: "<<balance[i]<<endl;

}getch();
    }
    void unsortedList::makeEmpty(){
length=0;
    }
    void unsortedList::replaceItem(){
int item,location,n,found;
string newName;
double balances;
cout<<"Enter the Account number: ";
cin>>n;
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){

    if(info[i]==n){

    found =1;
    location =i;
    }}
    if(found==1){

    cout<<"Account Number Found!"<<endl;
    cout<<"Account Name: "<<names[location]<<endl;
    cout<<"Account Balance Amount: "<<balance[location]<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter new Account name: ";
    cin>>newName;
    cout<<"Enter new Balance Amount: ";
    cin>>balances;
    names[location]=newName;
    balance[location]=balances;
    }
    else{
    cout<<"Account Number Not Found!";    }
    getch();
         }
     void unsortedList::deposit(){
 int location,n,found;
 double deposit;
 cout<<"Enter the Account number: ";
 cin>>n;
     for(int i=0;i<10;i++){

     if(info[i]==n){

    found =1;
    location =i;
    }}
    if(found==1){

    cout<<"Account number Found!"<<endl;
    cout<<"Account Name: "<<names[location]<<endl;
    cout<<"Account Balance: "<<balance[location]<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter Amount to Deposit ";
    cin>>deposit;
    balance[location]+=deposit;
    }
    else{
    cout<<"Account Number Not Found!";    }
   getch();
       }
      void unsortedList::withdraw(){
  int location,n,found;
  double deposit;
  cout<<"Enter the Account number: ";
  cin>>n;
      for(int i=0;i<10;i++){

      if(info[i]==n){

    found =1;
    location =i;
    }}
    if(found==1){

    cout<<"Account number Found!"<<endl;
    cout<<"Account Name: "<<names[location]<<endl;
    cout<<"Account Balance: "<<balance[location]<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter Amount to Withdraw: ";
    cin>>deposit;
    balance[location]-=deposit;
    }
    else{
    cout<<"Account Number Not Found!";    }
    getch();
        }


    int main(){
unsortedList usl;
int num,choice,del,rep;
string name,newName;
double balance;
do{
system("cls");
cout<<"\nMenu"<<endl;
cout<<"1.Register"<<endl;
cout<<"2.Deposit"<<endl;
cout<<"3.WithDraw"<<endl;
cout<<"4.Delete An Account"<<endl;
cout<<"5.Show All Accounts"<<endl;
cout<<"6.Edit An Account"<<endl;
cout<<"7.Delete All Accounts"<<endl;
cout<<"8.Exit"<<endl;
cin>>choice;
switch(choice){
    case 1:
        system("cls");
        cout<<"Enter Account name: ";
        cin>>name;
        cout<<"Enter Account number: ";
        cin>>num;
        cout<<"Enter the Initial Amount to be Deposited: ";
        cin>>balance;
        usl.insertItem(num,name,balance);
        break;
    case 2:
        system("cls");
        usl.deposit();
        break;
    case 3:
        system("cls");
        usl.withdraw();
        break;
    case 4:
        system("cls");
        usl.deleteItemAt();
        break;
    case 5:
        system("cls");
        usl.show();
        break;
    case 6:
        system("cls");
        usl.replaceItem();
        break;
    case 7:
        usl.makeEmpty();
        break;
  }}while(choice!=8);
  return 0;
      }
```

Comment: One problem might be that when you're removing an item, you're only move the `info` field, not the `name` and `balance` fields.

Comment: You might also want to format the code better, especially the indentation is bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when the list is empty or the some of the index is still empty it
>   contains a default element 0 and 1

You declare arrays as members of the class but you don't initialize them so expect to have anything in there. Like 0 or 1 or really big values. Here's a way to initialize it:

```
memset(info, 0, 10*sizeof(int)); // Consider putting 10 in a const.
```

**Also you should only be looping until length, not static array size**.

```
cout<<"Enter the Account number: ";
cin>>n;
    for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
```

Another problem:

```
int location,n,found;
```

You don't initialize those either and later,

```
if(found==1){
```

You're lucky you didn't type

```
if(found)
```

otherwise you would get a lot of false positive since `found` being unitialized, it is most likely never 0 like you think.

Comment: i put ur  memset code after the int info[10]; but i got this errors:

[Error]'info'is not a type
[Error]expected identifier before numeric constant
[Error] expected ','or'...'before numberi constant
[Error]ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'memset'with no type [-fpermissive]

Comment: btw i tried what uve said i initiate all the variables and the loop <length..and it seems it works fine after i tried to run it again it ddnt accept now 0 ,1...tnx a lot man for ur help..godbless

Comment: btw my last question is how can i delete an array element ,unlike this one my deletion is fake..users can see it that i just remove the array length thats why its not output on screen but the truth is its still there i move it in the end..in this code
for(int i=location;i<length-1;i++)
  
  info[i]=info[i+1];
  
  length--;
  cout<<"Account Deleted";}

Comment: @user3052514 The memset part needs to be but in the constructor. To implement the delete, I would only put the info variable to -1 and then reuse this spot later when/if you need to add another one. Please consider upvoting and accepting the answer if it helped you.